# Spring AntPathMatcher setCaseSensitive(false) doesn't work for get parameters

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, data-binding, form-parameter

I have following code:

pojo:

```
class MyBean{

    public String getValueName() {
        return valueName;
    }

    public void setValueName(String valueName) {
        this.valueName = valueName;
    }

    String valueName;
}
```

inside controller:

```
@ModelAttribute
    public MyBean createMyBean() {
        return new MyBean();
    }
    @RequestMapping(value = "/getMyBean", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String getMyBean(@ModelAttribute MyBean myBean) {
        System.out.println(myBean.getValueName());
        return "pathToJsp";
    }
```

configuration:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class Configiuration extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {


    ...

    @Override
    public void configurePathMatch(PathMatchConfigurer configurer) {
        AntPathMatcher matcher = new AntPathMatcher();
        matcher.setCaseSensitive(false);
        configurer.setPathMatcher(matcher);
    }
}
```

When I go to the url

```
localhost:8081/getMyBean?valueName=trololo
```

I see `trololo` in console

When I go to the url

```
localhost:8081/getMyBean?valuename=trololo
```

I see null in console.

How to resolve my problem?

Comment: Are you sure `WebConfig` is scanned by Spring (either by `@ComponentScan` or `<context:component-scan/>`)?

Comment: @Tunaki absolutely sure

Comment: **<context:component-scan base-package="com.terminal" >
        <context:include-filter type="annotation" expression="org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Aspect"/>
        <context:exclude-filter type="annotation" expression="org.springframework.stereotype.Controller"/>
    </context:component-scan>**

Comment: configuration located inside **package com.terminal.configuration;**

Comment: I have sibling class with configuration - methods from this class invoke properly. I am sure that problem unrelated twith component-scan

Comment: @Tunaki topic updated with more details

Comment: Is there a [`@EnableWebMvc`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/config/annotation/EnableWebMvc.html) somewhere scanned by Spring?

Comment: @Tunaki you are right. After adding this annotation method configurePathMatch invokes but it doesn't help to fix my problem

Comment: Yes, this is because the `PathMatcher` you configured is used to match URL path, i.e. to determine with controller method to call based of the URL. So I'm sure that if you navigate to `localhost:8081/GeTmYbEaN?valueName=trololo`, your method will be called just fine. I'm not sure how to go about the case insensitivity for object properties though (don't know if this is possible).

Comment: @ Tunak **localhost:8081/GeTmYbEaN?valueName=trololo** doesn;t work too